# How can COUNT be used multiple times when creating a view table?

Tags: mysql, sql

So, I am currently trying to create a View Table with the following info: EventCode, event name, the number of shows, the screen cost, the total screening cost (number of shows * screening cost), promotion cost, production cost, total cost (total screen cost + promotion cost + production cost), the expected
revenue (use the BaseTicketPrice), the actual revenue, the total discounts given (expected revenue - actual revenue) and the profit (all costs - actual revenue).

So there is a lot of information math involved in this View.

Also, the information comes from multiple tables, about 4.

I have to find the number of shows which would come from the table EventShow and then I have to use the number of shows in a later equation. How do I structure the count of a table and then use it again in an equation/aggregation?

I realize what I have below is really incorrect, but I'm mainly struggling on the COUNT portion right now.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW TicketDetails AS
    SELECT
        E.EventCode,
        E.EventName,
        E.EventShows Count(*) as NumberOfShows,
       (E.ScreeningCost * NumberOfShows) as TotalScreeningCost,
       (E.BaseTicketPrice * Ticket(Count(*))) as ExpectedRevenue,
        E.PromotionCost,
        E.ProductionCost,
       (TotalScreeningCost + E.PromotionCost + E.ProductionCost) as TotalCost,
       (E.BaseTicketPrice * TS.TicketsSolds) as ActualRevenue, 
       (ExpectedRevenue - ActualRevenue) as TotalDiscounts
       (TotalCost - ActualRevenue) as Profit
        FROM Event E, Ticket T, TicketSale TS, EventShow ES
        WHERE (E.EventCode = TS.EventCode);
```

Answer (score 0):

The select list is one the last clauses that get executed in sql. Any aliases defined in the select list can only be referred to in the order by and having clauses, but not in the select list or where clause.

Another issue will be that if you join multiple tables, you cannot count the rows returned from one of the tables using `count(*)` or `count(tablename.*)`, so you have to use a field from that table which cannot be null if a row is returned from that table - this should be a field you joined the table on. A simplified example based on your tables:

```
select e.eventcode, e.eventname, count(es.eventcode) as numberofshows, e.screeningcosts*count(es.eventcode) as totalscreeningcosts
from events e left join eventshows es
on e.eventcode=es.eventcode
group by e.eventcode, e.eventname, e.screeningcosts
```

I assumed that the 2 tables each have an eventcode field.